# How to style 404 page in WAMP server

Tags: php, html, css, http-status-code-404, wamp

I am using a WAMP server and I need to change the "404 not found page" style using CSS. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `httpd.conf` file, there will be an `ErrorDocument` section:

```
#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#
```

After that, add this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

That will set the error page to a file called `error.html`, and it is better than using `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 2):

**You can redirect 404 error pages using `.htaccess` file to your custom pages.**

Design your custom **404** page with using HTML/CSS. Once you have your 404 page setup, all you need to do is send visitors to incorrect url’s to this page. To do this just add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

You can place the **404** error template anywhere you want. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called `errormessages`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php
```

See this article, [**How to redirect your 404 error to a custom page**](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a **[core feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)** in Apache, and you can select a few methods of changing the 404 message.

To create your own custom page with HTML/CSS, this is one option you can put in your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my404.php
```

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess  add

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/custom/404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are many sites hosted on your server and you want a different message for each site, adding 
`ErrorDocument 404`  to .htaccess file is the way to go.

If you want the same error message to occur across all the websites, then setting ErrorDocument in httpd.conf is the way to go.