# 404 page not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using a WAMP server and I need to change the "404 not found page" style using htaccess. How can I do it?

"Not Found

The requested URL /viewprofile.php was not found on this server".Here is my htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*).htm$ viewprofile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ viewprofile.php?id=$2
RewriteRule viewads(.*)\.htm$ viewads.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*)&(.*)\.htm$ homeads.php?id=$2
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ profile_city.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ profile_cast.php?id=$1



RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Already Answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753912/how-to-style-404-page-in-wamp-server

Answer (score 1):

You may read official docs about [Custom Error Responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html)

In short, use this directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Lame_excuses/not_found.html
```

Make sure you have **[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) All** (or **FileInfo**)set in base config file.

Comment: @user1693607 did you read docs carefully? You need to have proper AllowOverride config.See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

In `404page.html` page you can put the content whatever you want to display for 404 not found. In your case "`The requested URL /viewprofile.php was not found on this server`"

Answer (score 0):

In your **`httpd.conf`** file, there will be an **`ErrorDocument`** section:

```
#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#
```

After that, add this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

That will set the error page to a file called error.html, and it is better than using .htaccess files.