# Not found: the requested URL /viewprofile.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, wampserver

I have a problem in my site, I cannot view the `viewprofile.php`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*).htm$ viewprofile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ viewprofile.php?id=$2
RewriteRule viewads(.*)\.htm$ viewads.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*)&(.*)\.htm$ homeads.php?id=$2
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ profile_city.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*).htm$ profile_cast.php?id=$1


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /viewprofile.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^waytonikah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://waytonikah.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If you give us some code then we will

Comment: I think I've seen the same question yesterday..

Comment: try tu put a `^` before the rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ viewprofile.php?id=$2` and then try to see if the url http://waytonikah.com/test.htm is working

Comment: possible duplicate of [404 page not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561575/404-page-not-found-error)

Answer (score 1):

This is a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^waytonikah.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://waytonikah.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule does this:

1. URL is `http://waytonikah.com/`, request is made
2. Is the Host **`waytonikah.com`**?
3. If yes, redirect to **`http://waytonikah.com/`**,
4. URL is `http://waytonikah.com/`, request is made
5. Is the Host **`waytonikah.com`**?
6. If yes, redirect to **`http://waytonikah.com/`**,

etc.