# How to change the WAMP 404 page?

Tags: php, html, windows, http, wamp

I can't get the default 404 page to change to my custom one.

I have read a few threads on here and followed them, but still nothing I keep getting this:

> [image]

Could someone please elaborate on how to change this? I need to set everything up on WAMP before uploading, thanks!

Comment: that link is broken. Set up everything on Wampp where?

Comment: Does the file `/test/404test.php` exist?

Comment: After changing the 404 document setting in config file, do you restart Apache ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753912/how-to-style-404-page-in-wamp-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the page 404test.php in a folder called test in your web root (as the message implies).

You may also want to look at the instructions given here:
[How to style 404 page in WAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753912/how-to-style-404-page-in-wamp-server)

Edit: Specifically, make sure in httpd.conf you have `ErrorDocument 404 /error.html` (replace /error.html with the path to your error page). And make sure you restart Apache after making changes to httpd.conf

Comment: I just used that file name as a test to show you that it doesn't go to my custom 404.

Comment: I've updated the question with more specific advice. You will need to make sure you've updated http.conf, restarted apache, and that the page actually exists. Have you done all these things? If so, what exactly is the problem?